# Add Integer to JList in java

Tags: java, int, jlist

Im making a jframe with two components. A list and a button. The list starts at 0 and everytime i press the button it increases by 1. So if i press the button, the value in the jlist changes from 0 to 1.

My question is, how can I add an integer to a jlist? (i tried the setText method just in case - only works for Strings)

Thanks 
EDIT: PART OF MY CODE (ActionListener)

```
            increase.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                counter++;
                System.out.println(counter);
                listModel.addElement(counter);
//              listModel.clear();
            }
        });
```

Comment: To change the value in the textbox use `new Integer(yourInteger).toString()`

Comment: @user3322273 its a JList in a JFrame not a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to add an int item to the JList, meaning a new int pops up in the list's display each time the button is pushed. You can create a `JList<Integer>` and add Integers (or boxed ints) to the JList's model, usually using `listModel.addElement(myInteger)`.

If you need to clear previous elements, do so ***before*** adding the element, not ***after***.  For example,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo2 extends JPanel {
   private DefaultListModel<Integer> dataModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<Integer> intJList = new JList<>(dataModel);

   public Foo2() {
      add(new JScrollPane(intJList));
      intJList.setFocusable(false);
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Int") {
         private int count = 0;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dataModel.clear();  // if you need to clear previous entries
            dataModel.addElement(count);
            count++;
         }
      }));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Foo2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }  
}
```

Comment: thanks works just fine. I seem to get another problem. So everytime i press the button it increases. But it also deletes the previous integer displayed. I used the clear method right after the listModel.addElement(counter); but it doesnt work. Im pretty sure im misplacing the clear method. But can you lemme know what could be wrong?

Comment: @Guest: sorry, but you have me confused. What do you mean by clear method, and why are you calling it? Please edit your original question and post your latest code. Click the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25627782/edit) below your question to allow you to edit it. In your edit window, click on the question mark for help adding your code.

Comment: sorry for confusing you. So what you told me works perfectly. What i need now is to clear the jlist everytime i press the button. So say i click the button. It increases the counter to 1 and displays 1 on the list. If i click the button again, it deletes 1 and prints 2. Ill attach part of the code

Comment: @Guest: If you need to clear the model, do so ***before*** adding the element, not ***after***.

Comment: i already figured it out, just added clear() before addElement() and it worked! Thanks for the help tho!